# SIGSEGV on JNIEnv->CallStaticObjectMethod

Tags: c, kotlin, raspberry-pi, java-native-interface, segmentation-fault

I'm trying to create a JThrowable in C code when an error value is returned from a native library. A SIGSEGV is generated when I call `(*env)->CallStaticObjectMethod(env, exceptionClass, mid, errCode);`.

This is the C code that creates the exception:

```c
jthrowable makeGPIOException(JNIEnv *env, int errCode) {
    printf("makeGPIOException %d\n", errCode);
    jclass exceptionClass = (*env)->FindClass(env, "com/nicholaspjohnson/kpigpio/exceptions/GPIOException");
    printf("excClass %p\n", (void*)&exceptionClass);
    jmethodID mid = (*env)->GetStaticMethodID(env, exceptionClass, "getProperThrowable", "(I)Ljava/lang/Class");
    printf("mid %p\n", (void*)&mid);
    jobject actualExceptionClass = (*env)->CallStaticObjectMethod(env, exceptionClass, mid, errCode);   
    printf("aec %p\n", (void*)&actualExceptionClass);
    jmethodID exceptionConstructorID = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, actualExceptionClass, "<init>", "()V");
    printf("eci %p\n", (void*)&exceptionConstructorID);
    return (*env)->NewObject(env, actualExceptionClass, exceptionConstructorID);
}
```

And the Kotlin class com.nicholaspjohnson.kpigpio.exceptions.GPIOException

```
open class GPIOException(reason: String): RuntimeException(reason) {
    companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        fun getProperThrowable(errCode: Int) : Class<out GPIOException> {
            println("getProperThrowable $errCode")
            return when(errCode) {
                //valid exceptions here, removed for clarity
                else -> throw RuntimeException("Bad errCode $errCode")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The debug printf's and println's return this message:

```
makeGPIOException -1
excClass 0xb6340a4c
mid 0xb6340a48
```

The kotlin code never prints anything, and immediately after the last line the SIGSEGV happens. This is the hs_err_pid.log

```
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0xb66b271c, pid=32064, tid=3056866416
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_65-b17) (build 1.8.0_65-b17)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (25.65-b01 mixed mode linux-arm )
# Problematic frame:
# V  [libjvm.so+0x2f171c]

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0xb6106b80):  JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_vm, id=32065, stack(0xb62f2000,0xb6342000)]
siginfo: si_signo: 11 (SIGSEGV), si_code: 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), si_addr: 0x00000000

Top of Stack: (sp=0xb63409b8)
0xb63409b8:   b6106b80 b6106cbc b6340a2c b66ad938
0xb63409c8:   b40015dc b66a11b8 00000000 b6340a34
0xb63409d8:   0000000c 89b37160 aa3a8538 b6106b80
0xb63409e8:   34333662 b6106b80 b6107238 00000617
0xb63409f8:   b6917bc0 00000000 00000000 b6340b04
0xb6340a08:   aa3a8538 b6106b80 b6340a5c b6e0eae0
0xb6340a18:   b66a0e7c b66ad8a4 b66a0e7c 00000000
0xb6340a28:   b6340a5c b40014a4 00000000 b6340a38 

Instructions: (pc=0xb66b271c)
0xb66b26fc:   e3a00003 ebffb390 e3500000 13a03001
0xb66b270c:   15c43000 e1a00004 e8bd8818 e92d4830
0xb66b271c:   e5913000 e1a05002 e5933004 e28db00c
0xb66b272c:   e1d321ba e5933008 e1a04000 e0833102 

Register to memory mapping:

  r0  = 0xb63409fc
0xb63409fc is pointing into the stack for thread: 0xb6106b80

  r1  = 0x00000000
0x00000000 is an unknown value

  r2  = 0xb6340a34
0xb6340a34 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0xb6106b80

  r3  = 0xb6340a34
0xb6340a34 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0xb6106b80

  r4  = 0xb6106b80
0xb6106b80 is a thread

  r5  = 0xb6106cbc
0xb6106cbc is an unknown value

  r6  = 0x00000000
0x00000000 is an unknown value

  r7  = 0x00000000
0x00000000 is an unknown value

  r8  = 0xb6340b04
0xb6340b04 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0xb6106b80

  r9  = 0xaa3a8538
{method} {0xaa3a8538} 'gpioInitialize' '()I' in 'com/nicholaspjohnson/kpigpio/PiGPIO'

  r10 = 0xb6106b80
0xb6106b80 is a thread

  fp  = 0xb6340a2c
0xb6340a2c is pointing into the stack for thread: 0xb6106b80

  r12 = 0x0000000c
0x0000000c is an unknown value

  sp  = 0xb63409b8
0xb63409b8 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0xb6106b80

  lr  = 0xb66ad938
0xb66ad938: <offset 0x2ec938> in /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-8-oracle-arm32-vfp-hflt/jre/lib/arm/client/libjvm.so at 0xb63c1000

  pc  = 0xb66b271c
0xb66b271c: <offset 0x2f171c> in /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-8-oracle-arm32-vfp-hflt/jre/lib/arm/client/libjvm.so at 0xb63c1000



Stack: [0xb62f2000,0xb6342000],  sp=0xb63409b8,  free space=314k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
V  [libjvm.so+0x2f171c]

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
j  com.nicholaspjohnson.kpigpio.PiGPIO.gpioInitialize()I+0
j  com.nicholaspjohnson.ledlights.Main.init()V+13
j  com.nicholaspjohnson.ledlights.Main.main([Ljava/lang/String;)V+23
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub

---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )
  0xb6180d20 JavaThread "Service Thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=32071, stack(0xac645000,0xac695000)]
  0xb617dcb8 JavaThread "C1 CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=32070, stack(0xac695000,0xac715000)]
  0xb617c7e0 JavaThread "Signal Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=32069, stack(0xac715000,0xac765000)]
  0xb6161198 JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=32068, stack(0xaca12000,0xaca62000)]
  0xb615fd88 JavaThread "Reference Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=32067, stack(0xaca62000,0xacab2000)]
=>0xb6106b80 JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_vm, id=32065, stack(0xb62f2000,0xb6342000)]

Other Threads:
  0xb615cfd8 VMThread [stack: 0xacab2000,0xacb32000] [id=32066]
  0xb61827b0 WatcherThread [stack: 0xac5c5000,0xac645000] [id=32072]

VM state:not at safepoint (normal execution)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread: None

Internal exceptions (10 events):
Event: 7.321 Thread 0xb6106b80 Exception <a 'java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException'> (0xad36f280) thrown at [/HUDSON/workspace/8-2-build-glinux-arm-vfp-hflt/jdk8u65/4987/hotspot/src/share/vm/runtime/sharedRuntime.cpp, line 605]
Event: 7.324 Thread 0xb6106b80 Exception <a 'java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException'> (0xad370388) thrown at [/HUDSON/workspace/8-2-build-glinux-arm-vfp-hflt/jdk8u65/4987/hotspot/src/share/vm/runtime/sharedRuntime.cpp, line 605]
Event: 7.330 Thread 0xb6106b80 Exception <a 'java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException'> (0xad371798) thrown at [/HUDSON/workspace/8-2-build-glinux-arm-vfp-hflt/jdk8u65/4987/hotspot/src/share/vm/runtime/sharedRuntime.cpp, line 605]
Event: 7.419 Thread 0xb6106b80 Exception <a 'java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException'> (0xad393a90) thrown at [/HUDSON/workspace/8-2-build-glinux-arm-vfp-hflt/jdk8u65/4987/hotspot/src/share/vm/runtime/sharedRuntime.cpp, line 605]
Event: 7.421 Thread 0xb6106b80 Exception <a 'java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException'> (0xad394ae0) thrown at [/HUDSON/workspace/8-2-build-glinux-arm-vfp-hflt/jdk8u65/4987/hotspot/src/share/vm/runtime/sharedRuntime.cpp, line 605]
Event: 7.425 Thread 0xb6106b80 Exception <a 'java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException'> (0xad395ff8) thrown at [/HUDSON/workspace/8-2-build-glinux-arm-vfp-hflt/jdk8u65/4987/hotspot/src/share/vm/runtime/sharedRuntime.cpp, line 605]
Event: 7.508 Thread 0xb6106b80 Exception <a 'java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException'> (0xad3b80b8) thrown at [/HUDSON/workspace/8-2-build-glinux-arm-vfp-hflt/jdk8u65/4987/hotspot/src/share/vm/runtime/sharedRuntime.cpp, line 605]
Event: 7.564 Thread 0xb6106b80 Exception <a 'java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException'> (0xad3c61f0) thrown at [/HUDSON/workspace/8-2-build-glinux-arm-vfp-hflt/jdk8u65/4987/hotspot/src/share/vm/runtime/sharedRuntime.cpp, line 605]
Event: 7.941 Thread 0xb6106b80 Exception <a 'java/lang/NoSuchMethodError': org.slf4j.impl.StaticMarkerBinder.getSingleton()Lorg/slf4j/impl/StaticMarkerBinder;> (0xad23dc40) thrown at [/HUDSON/workspace/8-2-build-glinux-arm-vfp-hflt/jdk8u65/4987/hotspot/src/share/vm/interpreter/linkReso
Event: 8.148 Thread 0xb6106b80 Exception <a 'java/lang/NoSuchMethodError': getProperThrowable> (0xad2c7910) thrown at [/HUDSON/workspace/8-2-build-glinux-arm-vfp-hflt/jdk8u65/4987/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jni.cpp, line 1559]

Events (10 events):
Event: 8.118 loading class org/apache/logging/log4j/core/layout/ByteBufferDestinationHelper
Event: 8.118 loading class org/apache/logging/log4j/core/layout/ByteBufferDestinationHelper done
Event: 8.126 loading class com/nicholaspjohnson/kpigpio/PiGPIO
Event: 8.126 loading class com/nicholaspjohnson/kpigpio/PiGPIO done
Event: 8.131 loading class java/lang/ClassLoaderHelper
Event: 8.132 loading class java/lang/ClassLoaderHelper done
Event: 8.139 loading class com/nicholaspjohnson/kpigpio/exceptions/GPIOException
Event: 8.139 loading class com/nicholaspjohnson/kpigpio/exceptions/GPIOException done
Event: 8.142 loading class com/nicholaspjohnson/kpigpio/exceptions/GPIOException$Companion
Event: 8.142 loading class com/nicholaspjohnson/kpigpio/exceptions/GPIOException$Companion done

VM Arguments:
java_command: com.nicholaspjohnson.ledlights.Main
java_class_path (initial): ledlights.main.jar
Launcher Type: SUN_STANDARD

Environment Variables:
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
SHELL=/bin/bash

Signal Handlers:
SIGSEGV: [libjvm.so+0x506638], sa_mask[0]=11111111011111111101111111111110, sa_flags=SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO
SIGBUS: [libjvm.so+0x506638], sa_mask[0]=11111111011111111101111111111110, sa_flags=SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO
SIGFPE: [libjvm.so+0x3fd4ec], sa_mask[0]=11111111011111111101111111111110, sa_flags=SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO
SIGPIPE: [libjvm.so+0x3fd4ec], sa_mask[0]=11111111011111111101111111111110, sa_flags=SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO
SIGXFSZ: [libjvm.so+0x3fd4ec], sa_mask[0]=11111111011111111101111111111110, sa_flags=SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO
SIGILL: [libjvm.so+0x3fd4ec], sa_mask[0]=11111111011111111101111111111110, sa_flags=SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO
SIGUSR1: SIG_DFL, sa_mask[0]=00000000000000000000000000000000, sa_flags=none
SIGUSR2: [libjvm.so+0x3fd650], sa_mask[0]=00000000000000000000000000000000, sa_flags=SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO
SIGHUP: [libjvm.so+0x3fda84], sa_mask[0]=11111111011111111101111111111110, sa_flags=SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO
SIGINT: [libjvm.so+0x3fda84], sa_mask[0]=11111111011111111101111111111110, sa_flags=SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO
SIGTERM: [libjvm.so+0x3fda84], sa_mask[0]=11111111011111111101111111111110, sa_flags=SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO
SIGQUIT: [libjvm.so+0x3fda84], sa_mask[0]=11111111011111111101111111111110, sa_flags=SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO


---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

OS:PRETTY_NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)"
NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="9"
VERSION="9 (stretch)"
ID=raspbian
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianForums"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianBugs"

uname:Linux 4.14.71+ #1145 Fri Sep 21 15:06:38 BST 2018 armv6l
libc:glibc 2.24 NPTL 2.24 
rlimit: STACK 8192k, CORE 0k, NPROC 3400, NOFILE 1048576, AS infinity
load average:0.24 0.15 0.46

Memory: 4k page, physical 443880k(246264k free), swap 102396k(88316k free)

vm_info: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (25.65-b01) for linux-arm-vfp-hflt JRE (1.8.0_65-b17), built on Oct  6 2015 16:19:04 by "java_re" with gcc 4.7.2 20120910 (prerelease)

time: Fri Aug 23 01:02:36 2019
elapsed time: 8 seconds (0d 0h 0m 8s)
```

Thank you for any help in advance!

Comment: You are printing the *addresses* of the exception class and MID, not their values. One of them must be zero. Check them, and display the pending exception if so. You cannot write correct JNI code without checking the result of every JNI call.

Comment: The return type of the signature in GetStaticMethodID is missing a `;`. If you implement the suggestions of @user207421 I suspect you will find that `mid` is 0.

Comment: And this in turn shows that you should not try to guess JNI method descriptor signatures. Use the output of `javap -s`. It is never wrong.

Comment: @user207421 You were correct, thank you! I had used javap -s, but figured that the semicolon was unnecessary. Thank you both!

Comment: @Botje You were correct, thank you! I had used javap -s, but figured that the semicolon was unnecessary. Thank you both!